# Add parameter to a Object from Entity on ViewData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Acutally I have an Entity with the following info:

```
public class PersonOE
    {
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public int? Age     { get; set; }
        public string City  { get; set; }
    }
```

My controllers use this object in different types of Views and inside a specific ViewModel I need to add an especific parameter to this model:

```
public string Style  { get; set; }
```

This is a simple example but in general, I don't want to add `Style` to my entity and I need to create an array of lists of "Person" main object on my view, like:

```
public class PersonStyleViewData : ViewModel
    {
        public List<PersonOE>[] ListPeople { get; set; }
        //I want to have the following object as "PersonOE" into this list
        //Name  
        //Age     
        //City  
        //Style  

    }
```

Is there any way to create this "ListPeople" structure with a `Style` variable without the need to add it to the entity ?

Comment: This is where the whole concept of Models (the "M" in MVC) comes into play. You shouldn't be using your data classes in your Views. Make models that only contain the information that you need (you can mix information from multiple data objects). Then pass that Model to the View.

Comment: @krillgar But I'm making the model to use into the view/controller.. Is that wrong too ?

Comment: You just aren't taking it far enough. In your model, you have a `List<PersonOE>`, but instead of having the collection of your data objects, you should have a collection of a model for that data object as well. So along those lines, Kyle's answer would work, but the terminology he uses doesn't make that distinction.

Comment: @krillgar would you mind to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518243/constructor-for-object-from-entity and check if I'm doing it right? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could create another class and use some inheritance

```
public class PersonOEWithStyle : PersonOE
{
    public string Style { get; set; }
}
```

The above class will have the properties `Name`, `Age`, `City`, and `Style`

Then just make your list of type `PersonOEWithStyle`.

Another way would instead of using a List, you could use something like a dictionary

`Dictionary<PersonOE, string> personStyle;`

It really depends on what you're using this for as far as the best approach.  But no, you can't 'add on' a property to an existing class in only some cases without actually making it part of the class.  Your best bet is probably to create some type of base class and derive from that.

Comment: Thanks for this ! Could you add a tip if I were to create a cast from PersonOE to PersonOEWithStyle object ? This new value could be null during the creation