# Constructor for object model similar from entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying my best to follow some MVC guidelines and for now, I have created a model with the fields I need from an entity I have. I have created the following Model class:

```
    public class PersonStyle
       {
            public string Name  { get; set; }
            public int? Age     { get; set; }
            public string City  { get; set; }
            public string Style { get; set; }
        }
```

My Entity is sometihng like:

```
     public class PersonOE
        {
            public string Name  { get; set; }
            public int? Age     { get; set; }
            public string City  { get; set; }
        }
```

Im trying to build a constructor for the following:

```
  PersonON personBus = new personBus();
  List<PersonStyle> personStyleList = new List<PersonStyle>(personBus.getPeople()); //getPeople(); returns a PersonOE list
```

For this all, I need suggestions on how to create the `PersonStyle` constructor that will put "null" into the only different variable from the `PersonOE` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use LINQ to generate your properties. Though, adding your Style to each of them could get a little harder to deal with, but you haven't given any input on where they're coming from. This is a quick and easy way to convert from your data to model objects.

```
List<PersonStyle> personStyleList = personBus.GetPeople()
                                        .Select(p => new PersonStyle {
                                            Name = p.Name,
                                            Age = p.Age,
                                            City = p.City
                                        });
```

Comment: THanks for this ! I hope now I'm closer to best practices :)